# 404 error file not found while insert data into database using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.4

I am new in laravel I am simply wants to insert form input field data into database using jquery ajax but now problem is that when I click on submit button it show `404` error but when I write `localhost/practice/public/save` in url then `(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. I don't know whay and where I am doing wrong? Please help me.

app/http/controllers/UserController.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use DB;

    class UserController extends Controller
    {
        public function save(Request $request)
        {
            $username = $request->input('username');
            $password = $request->input('password');
            $confirm_id = md5($username);
            $data = array(
                            'username'=>$username,
                            'password'=>$password,
                            'confirm_id'=>$confirm_id
                        );
            print_r($data);
        }
    }
```

resources/view/index.blade.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            username = $("#email").val();
            password = $("#password").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"username":username,"password":password,"_token":"{{csrf_token()}}"},
                url:"{{URL::to('save')}}",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#success").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

route/web.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/',function(){
    return view('index');
});
Route::post('save','UserController@save');
```

Comment: It's post request so you have to include CSRF token

Comment: I have already send csrf token check my jquery code

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a `post` request directly in `URL`. It will always return MethodNotAllowedHttpException(The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST)

So something wrong in ajax request.

`url:"{{URL::to('save')}}",`
Try to replace this `url: {{ url('save') }}`

Comment: Can you provide the url, you are getting when click on submit button and get 404 error.